# How can I use xmlreader with array in php

Tags: php, arrays, xmlreader

I want to create array with using xmlreader.Also,I have to use reader->depth function.If the depth of the xml file changes, I need to send this value into the array I created earlier.But ı cant write correctly because I'm losing the value of the array I created.

I tried the creat new array when the depth change.After that I pushed the array I created.

```
if($reader->depth != $depth){
    $ar[$j]=$reader->localName;
    $array[$array[$i]]=$ar[$j];
    $depth= $reader->depth;
}
```

Comment: I think not if be while loop

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
while ($xml->read()) { 

    if($reader->depth != $depth){
    $ar[$j]=$reader->localName;
    $array[$array[$i]]=$ar[$j];
    $depth= $reader->depth;

 }
}
```